# Most efficient way to filter prime numbers from a list of random numbers in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, python-3.x, primes

I have a list filled with random numbers and I want to return the prime numbers from this list. So I created these functions:

```
def is_prime(number):
    for i in range(2, int(sqrt(number)) + 1):
        if number % i == 0:
            return False

    return number > 1
```

And

```
def filter_primes(general_list):
    return set(filter(is_prime, general_list))
```

But I want to improve performance, so how can I achieve this?

Comment: There are *tons* of solutions out there especially on SO that show implementations of prime checking. Have you checked any of them?

Comment: Not sure if this would help performance since I don't have time to test anything,  but this `return True if number > 1 else False` can be reduced to this: `return number > 1`.

Comment: Yes, there are tons of solutions of prime checking, but none of them applies to the scenario of a list of random numbers.

Comment: @flpn: A number doesn't suddenly get less prime just because it is in a list.

Comment: The best, IMO, what you can do is use Miller Rabin as a prime testing algorithm.

Comment: How big are the numbers you have to check?

Comment: @Ryan, let's say I have 10 million numbers and each number can be between 0 and 10 million.

Comment: For 10  million numbers you need to consider using numpy or Cython

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes), taking about 0.17 seconds for primes under 10 million on PyPy 3.5 on my device:

```
from array import array
from math import isqrt

def primes(upper):
    numbers = array('B', [1]) * (upper + 1)

    for i in range(2, isqrt(upper) + 1):
        if numbers[i]:
            low_multiple = i * i
            numbers[low_multiple:upper + 1:i] = array('B', [0]) * ((upper - low_multiple) // i + 1)

    return {i for i, x in enumerate(numbers) if i >= 2 and x}
```

and the filter function:

```
filter_primes = primes(10_000_000).intersection
```

Comment: Once `i` reaches `sqrt(upper)` you have identified all the primes.

Comment: Does this sieve work with a list of random numbers?

Comment: @flpn: No, but if all your random numbers are from 0–10,000,000, the point is you can just get all the prime numbers in that range and check if each random number is in that set. Which is what this does with `filter_primes = primes(10_000_000).intersection` – just call `filter_primes(general_list)` as usual.

Answer (score 4):

3 rounds of the the Miller-Rabin test ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%2dRabin_primality_test ) using bases 2, 7, and 61, is known to accurately detect all primes <= 32 bit, i.e., anything that fits into a python `int`.

This is much, much faster than trial division or sieving if the numbers can be large.

If the numbers cannot be large (i.e., < 10,000,000 as you suggest in comments), then you may want to precompute the set of all primes < 10,000,000, but there are over 600,000 of those.

Answer (score 3):

How about this? I think It's a little better:

```
def filter_primes(general_list):
   return filter(is_prime, set(general_list))
```

This way we don't call `is_prime()` for same number multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

1. The Sieve of Eratosthenes is more efficient than Trial Division, the method you are using.
2. Your trial division loop can be made more efficient, taking about half the time.  Two is the only even prime number, so treat two as a special case and only deal with odd numbers thereafter, which will halve the work.

My Python is non-existent, but this pseudocode should make things clear:

```
def isPrime(num)

  // Low numbers.
  if (num <= 1)
    return false
  end if

  // Even numbers
  if (num % 2 == 0)
    return (num == 2)  // 2 is the only even prime.
  end if

  // Odd numbers
  for (i = 3 to sqrt(num) + 1 step 2)
    if (num % i == 0)
      return false
    end if
  end for

  // If we reach here, num is prime.
  return true;

end def
```

That `step 2` in the `for` loop is what halves the work.  Having earlier eliminated all even numbers you only need to test with odd trial divisors: 3, 5, 7, ...

Comment: It is not a sieve, it just tests the numbers supplied.  If you pass it the same number twice it will test that number twice.  A sieve will calculate a range of numbers once each and return the pre-calculated result when asked.

Answer (score 1):

```
def primes_list(num_list):
    divs = [2,3,5,7]
    primes = [x for x in set(num_list) if 0 not in {1 if ((x%i != 0) | (x in divs)) & (x > 0) else 0 for i in divs}]
    return primes
```

For this function, it takes a list, `num_list`, as a parameter. `divs` is a predefined, or rather hard coded, list of prime numbers less than 10 excluding 1. Then we use list comprehension to filter `num_list` for prime numbers as the variable `primes`.

Answer (score 0):

This is one more flavour of code to find the prime no of the range. The simple and easy way.

```
    def find_prime(n):
       if n <=1:
         return False
       else:
          for i in range(2, n):
              if n % i == 0:
                  return False
       return True
n = 10
x = filter(find_prime, range(n)) #you can give random no list too
print(list(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def is_prime(n):
  if n>1:
      for i in range(2,int(n**0.5)+1):
         if n%i==0: 
            return False
      return True
  else: return False
print([x for x in general_list if is_prime(x)])
```

would you try this... There is no need for the filter at all and you could simply apply set() to the general_list if there are duplicate elements in the list to optimize more.